# awk log with multiple fields - separate and re-sort

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, command-line

I have a file

**input.txt**

```
ID04120;2017-12-27;Office One;2017-12-27;Merchan Dep;2017-12-27;Sales Team 1;2017-12-27;Merchan Dep;2017-12-28;XXX4615;2017-12-28;XXX4615;2018-03-06;Office One;2018-03-06;Office One
ID04123;2017-12-28;Office One;2017-12-28;XXX4616;2018-04-05;Office One
ID04130;2017-12-29;Office One;2017-12-29;Room Fabric;2017-12-29;Support;2017-12-29;XXX4497;2018-01-17;Office One;2018-01-17;XXX4497;2018-01-17;Sales Team 3;2018-01-17;XXX4497;2018-03-13;Dev-sales-id;2018-03-14;XXX4497;2018-03-16;Dev Fabric
ID04266;2018-01-13;Office One;2018-01-13;XXX4186;2018-02-20;XXX4186;2018-02-22;XXX4186;2018-03-01;Office One
```

My log has different field numbers, may have 7 or more fields, is not a constant, separated by ";"

as in the example, where I can have 7,11,17 or 23 fields

I need to get the first entry XXX[0-9]{4} and its date(previous field), and what was the company sector before it and ordering them at the end of the line.

the entry XXX[0-9]{4} and its date(previous field) and its other entries XXX[0-9]{4} and their dates(previous field) do not need if, I need cut out.

Ex:

from
 
ID04123;2017-12-28;**Office One;2017-12-28;XXX4616**;2018-04-05;Office One

to
ID04123;2017-12-28;Office One;2018-04-05;Office One;**2017-12-28;Office One;XXX4616**

the output would look like this:

```
ID04120;2017-12-27;Office One;2017-12-27;Merchan Dep;2017-12-27;Sales Team 1;2017-12-27;Merchan Dep;2018-03-06;Office One;2018-03-06;Office One;2017-12-28;Merchan Dep;XXX4615
ID04123;2017-12-28;Office One;2018-04-05;Office One;2017-12-28;Office One;XXX4616
ID04130;2017-12-29;Office One;2017-12-29;Room Fabric;2017-12-29;Support;2018-01-17;Office One;2018-01-17;Sales Team 3;2018-03-13;Dev-sales-id;2018-03-16;Dev Fabric;2017-12-29;Support;XXX4497
ID04266;2018-01-13;Office One;2018-03-01;Office One;2018-01-13;Office One;XXX4186
```

I can try

```
awk --re-interval '
match($0,/[[:alnum:]]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2};XXX+[0-9]{4}+.*XXX+[0-9]{4}+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}|[[:alnum:]]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2};XXX+[0-9]{4}+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}/){
value2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
num=split(value2,array,";");
print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) array[1],array[num],substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1),array[2],array[1],array[3]
}'  OFS=";" input.txt
```

but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Seems OP could have multiple occurrences of regex in a line so according to shown sample changed the code to get the required output as follows.

```
awk -v s1=";" --re-interval -F";" '
match($0,/[a-zA-Z ]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2};X+[0-9]+.*X+[0-9]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z ]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2};X+[0-9]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}/){
   value2=value3=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
   split(value3,array,";");
   gsub(/;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2};X+[0-9]+/,"",value2);
   print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) value2 s1 substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1) s1 array[2] s1 array[1] s1 array[3];
   value2=""
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

Seems regex which is mentioned didn't work because string `object` mentioned by you in previous post changed to some other strings so I changed regex from matching string `object` to `[a-zA-Z]+` and it worked fine as follows.

```
awk -v s1=";" --re-interval -F";" '
match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2};X+[0-9]+.*X+[0-9]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2};X+[0-9]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}/){
  value2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  num=split(value2,array,";");
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) array[1] s1 array[num] s1 substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1) s1 array[2] s1 array[1] s1 array[3]
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Igor Torres, your output doesn't look consistent, please do check this code and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: output its correct, it works :-) ... only the department name is being cut at the end

Comment: output -> ID04123;2017-12-28;Office One;2018-04-05;Office One;2017-12-28;One;XXX4616 

and the end should be  2017-12-28;Office One;XXX4616

Comment: looking attention, the input.txt example on line 3 did not work. Did not bring all the fields
ID04130;2017-12-29;Office One;2017-12-29;Room Fabric;2017-12-29;Support;2018-01-17;Office One;2018-01-17;Sales Team 3;2018-03-13;Dev-sales-id;2018-03-16;Dev Fabric;2017-12-29;Support;XXX4497
ID04130;2017-12-29;Office One;2017-12-29;Room Fabric;2017-12-29;Support;                                                                      2018-03-16;Dev Fabric;2017-12-29;Support;XXX4497

Comment: @IgorTorres, I have fixed the problem for semi colon coming in between Office and One strings but not sure what you require in another output, request you to please be more clear in it and let me know a FIX pattern in CODE TAGS in comments or post by using `{}` and backtick in commands and let me know then.

Comment: @IgorTorres, ok, I have analysed your output and prepared code as per your shown samples only, check my EDIT and let me know then, how it goes.

Comment: I get the error:  source line number 1. I did not find an error in the syntax of the commands

Comment: I got, with -F ";" was giving error ... worked the change you made ... just the line with "ID04123" brought only "One" instead of "Office One". in the other lines brought the composite name "Merchan Dep" and "Office One"

Comment: @IgorTorres, cool, check my EDIT for that 2nd line too and let me know then?

Comment: It worked. perfect... tks...  in second [a-zA-Z] include a space and show